# Hot reloading not working with compound components

Tags: xcode, react-native, hot-reload

So let's say that I have a compound component like this

```
const TestComponent = ({children}) => {
   return <view>{children}</view>
}

TestComponent.Footer = function Footer(props:{sampleProp}) {
   return <text>{sampleProp}</text>
}
```

If I make a change to TestComponent.Footer, xcode will trigger the hot reload, but I won't see any changes until I exit the app and come back. Is there a way that I can fix this?